# How do I choose the correct random variable?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Here is the question, from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NzhXipwiz_E)

> In a barn, 100 chicks sit peacefully in a circle. Suddenly, each chick
>   randomly pecks the chick immediately to its left or right. What is the
>   expected number of unpecked chicks?

So if the chicks are equally likely to peck left or right, the answer is 25.

If we consider a single chick, the chance it is pecked is $3/4$ and the chance it isn't is $1/4$.

Let the random variable be

$$Z = \begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if chick is pecked} \\
1, & \text{if chick is not pecked}
\end{cases}$$

and so for each chick $$E[Z_i] = 0 * P(0) + 1 * P(1)$$
$$= 1/4$$

And by the *linearity of expectation*, we get 25.

$E[Z_i]$ is basically the probability that chick $i$  is not pecked. By my understanding, $Z$ can map any value to any outcome, it's our choice.

So what if we reversed, and had

$$Z = \begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if chick is pecked} \\
0, & \text{if chick is not pecked}
\end{cases}$$

Then $E[Z_i] = 3/ 4$, and our answer would be 75.

Or what if we had

$$Z = \begin{cases}
331,  & \text{if chick is pecked} \\
798, & \text{if chick is not pecked}
\end{cases}$$

then $E[Z_i] = 1791/ 4$, and the sum of the expected values would be 44,775. How do we choose the correct values for the random variables, or am I interpreting the results wrong?

I really don't understand the point of random variables. We could have easily deduced the answer 25, by saying that there is a 25% chance a chick is not pecked, and so for 100 chicks, 25 of them will be not be pecked. We really don't even need to talk about expected value either.

Comment: I think it is more about how you interpret what $Z$ represents. In the cases where set the $Z$ values to 0/1 and 1/0, it just so happens that the expected value ends up equalling the probability that a chick is or is not pecked. When you assign the values 331/798 we need to interpret $Z$ in a different way, it could be for example, the value of a chick to the farmer and $E[Z_i]$ ends up being the expected value of the $i^{th}$ chick.

Comment: I guess I just don't understand the whole point of random variables, let me extend my question.

Comment: If Z is the value of a chick to a farmer, what would 44,775 represent?

Comment: The random variable you're really interested in is the number of unpecked chicks. Call this variable $Y$. It can take values between $0$ and $50$. We have $Y = Z_1 + Z_2 + \dots + Z_{100}$, where the variables $Z_i$ are defined as you defined them the first time. This would not be true if you defined $Z_i$ the other ways. The way the concept of a random variable helped in this instance is that you were able to analyze a complicated variable, $Y$, in terms of much simpler variables.

Comment: Okay, $Y=Z_1+Z_2+⋯+Z_{100}$  does give me the answer, and if I defined them the second way, we get the expected number of chicks that were pecked. It makes intuitive sense, but again, for the answer, $Z_i$ is just the probability of a chick not getting pecked. What's the point of random variables here?

Comment: When you take the expectation, you're always taking the expectation of *something*. That something is always a random variable. Here, $Y$ is actually quite a complicated random variable, even though it is the sum of simple ones.

Comment: Anyway, if that seems too easy, here's another question. What is the expected value of the *square* of the number of unpecked chicks? The answer is 631.25. You get the answer by expanding the expression for $Y^2$, and evaluating the expected value of $Z_i Z_j$ in different cases. The cases $j = i$ and $j = i \pm 2$ (cyclically modulo 100) need to be treated separately.

Comment: "expected value of the *square* of the number of unpecked chicks", I'm having trouble understanding what this means. Isn't it just the square of the number of unpecked chicks? 625?

Comment: Do you think the square of the number of unpecked chicks is _always_ 625? Never 576 and never 676?

Comment: Oh yea, I guess it could be those values too.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2282622/expected-number-of-unpecked-chicks-nyt-article